# Automatically adding mark tag using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How may I automatically add a mark tag to HTML content? I'd like to highlight the word "milk", as follows:

Word : **milk**

```
<mark>milk</mark>
```

---

**Example :**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Do not forget to buy milk today.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Like that :**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
Do not forget to buy <mark>milk</mark> today.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: automatically means? any event `onclick` or `onload` or `onselect`

Comment: Note that the duplicate question requests the use of a `span` tag, but the technique is *exactly* the same, you just need to change the tag name

Comment: @prasad with onselect all words "milk"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Regex (regular expression) to find the word "milk" and replace it, as follows:

```js
var key ='milk';
var regex = new RegExp(key,'g');
var text = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML;
console.log(text);
var newText =  text.replace(regex,'<mark>'+key+'</mark>' );
console.log(newText);
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = newText;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="text">
   Do not forget to buy milk today.
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Or, you may simply write:

```js
 
 document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML.replace(/(milk)/g,'<mark>$1</mark>' );
```

```html
  <p id="text"> Do not forget to buy milk today. </p>
```

Comment: Sir , @XYZ but not work for me ,  `<html>
<head>

<script>
var key ='milk';
var regex = new RegExp(key,'g');
var text = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML;
console.log(text);
var newText =  text.replace(regex,'<mark>'+key+'</mark>' );
console.log(newText);
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = newText;
</script>

</head>
<body>


<p id="text">
Do not forget to buy milk today.
</p>

</body>
</html>`

Comment: @moon93 It is working for me.Created fiddle . http://jsfiddle.net/v0qwy58u/1/

Comment: ok , thank you @XYZ :)